# Why is my create-react-app boilerplate repo so large? Is this normal?

Tags: reactjs, size, create-react-app

After running "npx create-react-app projectname" the directory created is 242mb in size. Is this normal?

Do I need all this or is there a way to reduce the directory size?

Comment: Check how big is the node modules folder alone..

Comment: But you will create npm build to produce production build which is of course way smaller

Comment: WOW! That's pretty much the entire project. Do I need all this?

Comment: pretty much - you can try deleting a few node modules you don't like and see what happens ;)

Comment: Check npm instructions for building production releases.

Comment: Yes, this is normal.